# show users list in zoho crm

Tags: crm, zoho

I am a new guy in zoho CRM.I am trying to show the list of users which will be searched by a zoho manager. Is there any API to find out the list?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getUsers method to get the list of users in your organization.

https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/getusers.html